# Tracking costs on tasks with multiple resources

Tags: ms-project, ms-project-server-2013, project-online

I have 4 resources assigned to a 1 day task.  Each has a standard rate of $50/hr.  When I look at a resource cost report, it shows each person as working 8 hrs and a cost of $400, for a total of $1600.  How would I go about setting up the resources, so that each is credited for only 2hrs at $50/hr = $100 for a grand total of $400?  Would I have to assign each person at only 25% time on the task?

Please advise.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can go to View -> Details -> Task Form, and set each resource to 2 hrs. on the task. You can also just make the task duration 2 hrs, as long as your Task Type is not set to Fixed Work.